# Converting x/y values in camera view to pan/tilt values

Tags: math, trigonometry, point

If I have a camera which gives out 360 degree pan (x) and tilt (y) values, and I want to get the pan and tilt values of where I have my cursor in the camera's view, how would I convert that?

More info:
It's a Flash/AS3 project.
The pan and tilt values are from the center of the camera view.
Camera view size is 960x540.

Comment: I do not think you have supplied enough information for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it with a bit more info and tried to rephrase.. don't really know if it's any easier to understand what I'm after but I hope so.

Comment: Better, but you need to define what pan and tilt values mean.  Specifically, what is the relation between the entire domain of the pan and tilt values (360 degrees) to the total screen view; i.e., how much of the pan total and tilt total does the screen view take up?

Comment: Oh.. that's one of the things I don't actually know. The original image is 4552x2276 but then it's been processed by some software into a swf panorama where I can't really say if it kept those dimensions.

Comment: Ok, if we assume that if I'm looking straight into my monitor we have some vector pointing the screens direction so to speak. And if you move the mouse up and right on the screen, you want to know the delta angle in pan/tilt so you can update your camera so it points in that direction?

Comment: Sort of yes.. I'm still trying to figure outwhat delta angle is sorry. :) If I click somewhere within the camera's view, I'd like the camera to move and center on where I clicked, like you say. So I have to convert those x/y coordinates I get from the cursor within the 960x540 camera view to pan/tilt values.

Comment: Do you still have problems with this?

Answer (score 1):

You gave the "view" size in pixels.  What you need to know is the Field of View (FOV), which is measured in degrees.  From that you can tell the number of degrees from center to the image edges.

You might be able to find the FOV in your camera's technical specifications.  (It's determined by the detector array size and the focal length).  Alternatively, you could try measuring it.  Here's a webpage that explains how:

http://www.panohelp.com/lensfov.html